# validation rule with 3 required fields

Tags: validation-rule

I need to create a validation rule when an opportunity stage is closed lost, 3 fields must be filled in and the profile must be different from the director (directors do not need to fill in the fields). I have this validation rule but it is not working, it is allowing to save the opportunity even without all the fields filled in.
Loss_Reason__c and Fase_de_Declinio__c is picklist field and Data_Declinio__c is a date field.

```
AND(
    ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Closed Lost"), 
    ISBLANK(TEXT(Loss_Reason__c))
    && ISBLANK(TEXT( Fase_de_Declinio__c )) 
    && ISBLANK( Data_Declinio__c)) 
    && $Profile.Name != "Diretor de Expansão"
)
```

Comment: Brief note: Mixing `&&` and `||` with `AND()` and `OR()` is not recommended. Best to just pick one and stick with it. In this situation, the `&&` have no effect and just make it harder to read (and maintain) the formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The validation rules only trigger when the condition evaluates to true. Therefore, you would need to use a combination of AND and OR statements:

```
AND(
  ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Closed Lost"), 
  OR(
    ISPICKVAL(Loss_Reason__c,''),
    ISPICKVAL(Fase_de_Declinio__c,''),
    ISBLANK(Data_Declinio__c)
  ),
  $Profile.Name != "Diretor de Expansão"
)
```

However, it is **strongly** recommended that you do *not* do this. Make three separate validation rules, so you can assign the error to the correct field:

```
AND(
  ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Closed Lost"), 
  ISPICKVAL(Loss_Reason__c,''),
  $Profile.Name != "Diretor de Expansão"
)
```

---

```
AND(
  ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Closed Lost"), 
  ISPICKVAL(Fase_de_Declinio__c,''),
  $Profile.Name != "Diretor de Expansão"
)
```

---

```
AND(
  ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Closed Lost"), 
  ISBLANK(Data_Declinio__c),
  $Profile.Name != "Diretor de Expansão"
)
```

This will make it so users can easily identify which field(s) need to be filled in, instead of failing up to three separate times.

Comment: It worked, thank you very much!